# How to create a matrix with floats in C

Tags: c

I'm reading a text file which contains a matrix, and trying to save said matrix in a matrix, but I believe I'm not doing it correctly since when I compile the program I get the error *subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector*. Here's the code (*n_rows* and *n_cols* is the number of columns and rows of the matrix):

```
float kernel[n_rows];
float aux;
for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++){
    float row[n_cols];
    for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++){
        fscanf(f, "%f", &aux);
        row[j] = aux;
    kernel[i] = *row;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++){
        printf("%f ", kernel[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The problem it's in the *printf* part, so my matrix it's not correctly arranged. What's the correct way of doing it?

Comment: `float kernel[n_rows]` defines a 1D matrix you are trying to create a 2D matrix so it should look like `float kernel[n_rows][n_cols]` you have other problems but this is the first one you need to solve.

Comment: And it is disallowed to leak pointer to stack local array `float row[n_cols];` after the end of the block `}` where it was declared. This array is actually freed at the end of current iteration (`}` of first for loop), and next array created at the same memory address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify your code as follows:

- **Make `kernel` an array of pointers** - this will fix the compile problem you see
- **Allocate each row *dynamically*** - this will fix the problem with using temporary memory for your rows
- **Make the assignment outside the nested loop** - this will address a small efficiency issue.

Here is one way to fix it:

```
float *kernel[n_rows];
for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++){
    float *row = malloc(sizeof(float)*n_cols);
    for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++){
        fscanf(f, "%f", &row[j]);
    }
    kernel[i] = row;
}
```

Comment: Remember the `malloc`ated rows must be `free`d later.

Answer (score 3):

You create your matrix `kernel` as a 1-dimensional array. You actually want a 2D array (`float kernel[n_rows][n_cols]`).

Note you'd still have to change your row-fill code to make it work:

```
float *row = kernel[i];
for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++){
    fscanf(f, "%f", &aux);
    row[j] = aux;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know n_rows and n_cols ahead of time, then define kernel as:
    kernel[n_rows][n_cols];

As written, your row[n_cols] definition is on the stack, so while you can populate a row, the value of kernel[i] will be set to point to this stack-based array, and it will get clobbered each time through the loop.

By defining a two-dimensional kernel, you avoid this.

```
float kernel[n_rows][n_cols];
for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++){
        fscanf(f, "%f", &kernel[i][j]);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++){
        printf("%f ", kernel[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

If you do not know n_rows and n_cols up front, then you need to malloc an array of n_rows row pointers once you determine n_rows. Then loop for each row and malloc a float array for each row and point to it as shown by @dasblinkenlight